# Not able to build android apk using Unity.Gradle build fail

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

Here is what the stacktrace gives me

I installed unity using unity hub and set JAVA_HOME environment variable

Can someone please point me where it is going wrong?

```
1.BuildFailedException: Main Gradle template is not used in this build. ARCore SDK for Unity requires gradle plugin version >= 3.6.0. Nevigate to 'Project Settings > Player > Android Tab > Publish Settings > Build', check 'Custom Gradle Template'. Then edit the generated file 'Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle' by adding dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.'. GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidSupportPreprocessBuild.CheckMainGradle () (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Editor/ARCoreAndroidSupportPreprocessBuild.cs:135) GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidSupportPreprocessBuild.OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Editor/ARCoreAndroidSupportPreprocessBuild.cs:59) GoogleARCoreInternal.PreprocessBuildBase.OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Editor/PreprocessBuildBase.cs:52) UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+<>c_DisplayClass15_0.b_1 (UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport bpp) (at :0) UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InvokeCallbackInterfacesPair[T1,T2] (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] oneInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationOne, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] twoInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationTwo, System.Boolean exitOnFailure) (at :0) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler()

2.Error building Player: BuildFailedException: Main Gradle template is not used in this build. ARCore SDK for Unity requires gradle plugin version >= 3.6.0. Nevigate to 'Project Settings > Player > Android Tab > Publish Settings > Build', check 'Custom Gradle Template'. Then edit the generated file 'Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle' by adding dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.'.

3.Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 0 seconds (111 ms) 0x00007FF61BAE837C (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack 0x00007FF61BAEC331 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack 0x00007FF61A1BAE95 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007FF61C76BE7E (Unity) DebugStringToFile 0x00007FF61BB47735 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000012782FEB3AB (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object) 0x0000012782FEB24B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 0x0000012782FEA90E (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x0000012782FEA66A (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 0x0000012782FB3B33 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 0x0000012782FABDB3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 0x0000012782FAB44B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool) 0x0000012782FA90D3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun () 0x000001273B895955 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FFD1900D6B0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F92912 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F9B96F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 0x00007FF61BA51276 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF61BA50EB9 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF61BA50C41 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF6199C2A4F (Unity) BuildPlayerWithLastSettings 0x00007FF6195D6A6C (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMenuItem 0x00007FF6195D651B (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMainMenuItem 0x00007FF61A814C25 (Unity) EditorApplication_CUSTOM_ExecuteMenuItem 0x0000012782FA8BBE (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:ExecuteMenuItem (string) 0x0000012782FA8A8B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.MenuItemEntryDiscoveryInfo:<.ctor>b_7_0 (UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutArguments) 0x0000012782FA1FF1 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.Trigger:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.IContextManager) 0x000001274069FAA3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutController:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 0x000001274069F60B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutIntegration:EventHandler () 0x000001274069F33B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler () 0x000001273B895955 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FFD1900D6B0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F92912 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F9B96F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 0x00007FF61BA5AA2E (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007FF61BA5475D (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007FF61BA4E745 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007FF618D73E4E (Unity) Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler 0x00007FF6196B4E71 (Unity) CallGlobalInputEvent 0x00007FF61A1E35C0 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages 0x00007FF61A1DB709 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc 0x00007FFD5B175C7D (USER32) CallWindowProcW 0x00007FFD5B175672 (USER32) DispatchMessageW 0x00007FF61A1E0806 (Unity) MainMessageLoop 0x00007FF61A1EAAC8 (Unity) WinMain 0x00007FF61D209A32 (Unity) _scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007FFD5C597BD4 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007FFD5CA2CE51 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

4.UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in :0 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0 0x00007FF61BAE837C (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack 0x00007FF61BAEC331 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack 0x00007FF61A1BAE95 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007FF61C76BE7E (Unity) DebugStringToFile 0x00007FF61BB47735 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000012782FEB3AB (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object) 0x0000012782FEB24B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 0x0000012782FEA90E (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x0000012782FEA66A (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 0x0000012782FABF1B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 0x0000012782FAB44B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool) 0x0000012782FA90D3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun () 0x000001273B895955 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FFD1900D6B0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F92912 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F9B96F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 0x00007FF61BA51276 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF61BA50EB9 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF61BA50C41 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x00007FF6199C2A4F (Unity) BuildPlayerWithLastSettings 0x00007FF6195D6A6C (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMenuItem 0x00007FF6195D651B (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMainMenuItem 0x00007FF61A814C25 (Unity) EditorApplication_CUSTOM_ExecuteMenuItem 0x0000012782FA8BBE (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:ExecuteMenuItem (string) 0x0000012782FA8A8B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.MenuItemEntryDiscoveryInfo:<.ctor>b_7_0 (UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutArguments) 0x0000012782FA1FF1 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.Trigger:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.IContextManager) 0x000001274069FAA3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutController:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 0x000001274069F60B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutIntegration:EventHandler () 0x000001274069F33B (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler () 0x000001273B895955 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FFD1900D6B0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F92912 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFD18F9B96F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 0x00007FF61BA5AA2E (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007FF61BA5475D (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007FF61BA4E745 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007FF618D73E4E (Unity) Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler 0x00007FF6196B4E71 (Unity) CallGlobalInputEvent 0x00007FF61A1E35C0 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages 0x00007FF61A1DB709 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc 0x00007FFD5B175C7D (USER32) CallWindowProcW 0x00007FFD5B175672 (USER32) DispatchMessageW 0x00007FF61A1E0806 (Unity) MainMessageLoop 0x00007FF61A1EAAC8 (Unity) WinMain 0x00007FF61D209A32 (Unity) _scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007FFD5C597BD4 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007FFD5CA2CE51 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Did you perform the steps the error directs you to? `Nevigate to 'Project Settings > Player > Android Tab > Publish Settings > Build', check 'Custom Gradle Template'. Then edit the generated file 'Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle' by adding dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.'`

Comment: It actually shouldn't be needed right?

I have project on other systems that don't need it.

I don't want to export my project, which I believe is the use of gradle.

noob here

Comment: Having a custom gradle template has nothing to do with exporting the project. It's just a text file that you can edit to add dependencies and such. It seems like since the error message is trying to tell you what to do you should at least try it. It seems to be a problem they anticipated.

Comment: Is it needed though?

Actually i did that too and then it asks me to enable launcher gradle and few more stuffs ultimately leading to other error.

Which is that manifest can't patch the apk or something(unsure about this).

Comment: i am getting merger manifest error while doing that.It asks to check main gradle template and launcher gradle template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > External Tools > Android > Gradle` Installed with Unity. Clear the option, and specify a custom version of 5.6.4 or later. See Gradle build tool for downloads.

[image: A screenshot of the External Tools, Android pane showing a manually specified Gradle path]

Go to `Project Settings > Player > Android tab > Publishing Settings > Build`, and select Custom Gradle Template.

[image: A screenshot of the Publishing Settings, Build pane showing Custom Gradle Template selected]

Edit the generated file `Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle`, and set the dependency `com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.6.0` or later based on the Gradle version you use.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Must be Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0 or later. For a list of
        // compatible Gradle versions refer to:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
    }
}
```

For more: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/android-11-build

Comment: Was this answer copy-pasted from https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/android-11-build, or did they copy it from here?

Comment: no. I did it from my personal experience. I am a professional game developer having more 2 years of experience.